# What framework to build my own CMS in Java?

Tags: java, frameworks, content-management-system

I want to build my own CMS in Java. What framework/technologies i should use to do this?

I was thinking on Spring, Play framework, GWT or maybe Spring Roo.

Ofc im not going to build the best & biggest CMS on the Earth.

Comment: There's no "should", use whatever you're the most comfortable with.

Comment: Sure, but i want to lern some new for me freamwork and pick one the best for this kind of application. So what i like is not important here.

Answer (score 1):

For the back end - I've worked on one using JackRabbit implementation of JCR (Java Content repository) behind it.

The backend and caching worked well, unfortunately our front end wasn't great so don't have a recommendation for you there.  However did find there are a variety of open source CMS modules out there if you would prefer to start with one of them rather than build your own - though I see from your question you may be doing this as a learning experience, and want to develop your own.

Steve